# Custom react-native project directory structure

Tags: react-native

When initializing a react native project with `react-native init NativeApp` a new directory with a flat project structure is created.

I already have a project directory and I do not want to pollute the root directory excessively. What I want to achive is a root directory that looks like this:

```
MyProject
| - package.json
| - .gitignore
| - .gitattributes
| - README.md
| - .env
| - .git
| - Server
|   | - server.js
|   | - <other server files>
|
| - OtherProjectFolder
| - node_modules
| - NativeApp
    | - android
    | - ios
    | - app.json
    | - index.android.js
    | - index.ios.js
    | - ...
```

In words, I would like the react application to share package.json and node_modules etc. with the rest of my project, without keeping all the application files in the root directory.

Attempting to achieve this, I just moved the package.json, gitignore, node_modules and git files from the NativeApp directory to the MyProject directory, and used the command `react-native run-android --root NativeApp`, but then the build fails.

How do I reorganize the react native directory structure?

Comment: 1 year 8 months later i'm revisiting this problem. Found this that might be of some help: https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/7

Will follow up eventually